# React Ionic (v5): IonReactRouter & IonRouterOutlet Not Working as Expected

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm fairly new to React and Ionic. What I'm attempting to accomplished is to create a "protected route". I create a simple context called `AuthContext`:

```
import { createContext, Dispatch } from 'react';

/**
 * Context interface for AuthAuthentication/Authorization
 *
 * @property isAuthenticated
 * @property dispatch
 *
 * @interface
 */
interface AuthDefaultContext {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    dispatch: Dispatch<any>
}

/**
 * Authentication/Authorization context for managing
 * authenticating/ed and authorizing/ed users
 */
export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthDefaultContext>({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    dispatch: () => {}
});
```

and FunctionalComponent called `ProtectedRoute`:

```
interface ProtectedRouteProps {
    ProtectedComponent: FunctionComponent,
    routePath: string
}

export const ProtectedRoute: FunctionComponent<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ ProtectedComponent, routePath }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`loading protected route '${routePath}' with component ${ProtectedComponent.name}`)
    }, [ProtectedComponent, routePath] );

    return (
        <AuthContext.Consumer>
            {
                ({ isAuthenticated }) => (
                    <Route path={ routePath } render={ () => isAuthenticated ? <ProtectedComponent/> : <Redirect to="/login" /> }/>
                )
            }
        </AuthContext.Consumer>
    );
}
```

In my main app component I wrap the `IonReactRouter` inside the `AuthContext.Provider` like so:

```
        <IonApp>
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated: authenticated, dispatch: dispatch }}>
                <IonReactRouter>
                    <IonRouterOutlet>
                        <Route path="/login" component={ Login } exact={ true } />
                        <ProtectedRoute routePath="/welcome" ProtectedComponent={ Welcome }/>
                        <ProtectedRoute routePath="/search" ProtectedComponent={ Dummy }/>
                    </IonRouterOutlet>
                </IonReactRouter>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </IonApp>
```

The issue that I am having is that above works fine for the regular Route and first ProtectedRoute, but the `/search/` does not work. The uri path changes in the browser url to `/search` but the dummy component doesn't render.

I noticed that if you swap `<IonReactRouter>` & `<IonRouterOutlet>` like so:

```
            <IonRouterOutlet>
                <IonReactRouter>
                    .....
                </IonReactRouter>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
```

all of the routes works but you lose the animation effect provided by the `IonRouterOutlet`. The navigation docs on Ionics website has the `IonReactRouter` wrapping `IonRouterOutlet` so I am assuming that's the correct implementation.

If I change the `ProtectedRoute`'s to just the standard react `Route` all routes work fine with the animations. So the issue has to be with my Implementation of the `ProtectedRoute` component, I just can't figure it out. Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:

I still haven't found a solution for this issue, so I removed the IonRouterOutlet which seems to be the root cause. When doing so, everything works as expected. I posted this issue on the Ionic forum so when/if I get an answer, I'll post it here.

Thanks,

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue! However, have you tried setting the `exact` attribute on the `route` for the ProtectedComponent?

Comment: Working (not responsive):
```<UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUserAttributes }}>
      <IonApp>
        <IonReactRouter>
          <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
            <Menu appPages={appPages} />
            <div id="main">
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/home" exact={true} component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/login" exact={true} component={LoginPage} />
                <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" exact>
                  <DashboardPage />
                </ProtectedRoute>
              </Switch>
            </div>```

Comment: @DHFW I've tried using exact on the protected route, I ended up with some odd routing behavior. You're is a bit different than mine, looks like you're using a IonSplitPain without IonRouterOutline, which seems fine. In may use case, I'm rendering each route as a page without the splitpain with the IonRouterOutlet. The outlet adds the "native" animation with loading an  IonPaage. Thank you for input. If you have anymore ideas feel free to post :)

Answer (score 5):

IonRouterOutlet expects its children to be either Routes or "Route like", which means the children need to have the same basic props that a Route does.

So, for your ProtectedRoute, it should work if you rename your incoming props `routePath` to `path` and `ProtectedComponent` to `component`.

I put together a working sample repo starting with your code here: https://github.com/elylucas/ionic-react-protected-route

Let me know if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've found that using the `render` prop on a `Route` in an `IonRouterOutlet` breaks it.

In your case you would have to replace the following:

```
<Route
  path={routePath}
  render={() => isAuthenticated ? <ProtectedComponent/> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
/>
```

With something like this:

```
{
  isAuthenticated ?
    <Route path={routePath} component={ProtectedComponent} /> :
    <Redirect to="/login" />
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full github project with an example?

Comment: @LarsFlieger I think this JSX is scoped and straight forward enough, no need for a GitHub project.

Comment: True, however if you combine this with GuestRoutes (You get redirected to protected router after login) it will not work... :) So I was wondering in which context this was created.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had some pages nested in a reusable component "BasicPage" which caused problems:

```
interface BasicPage extends RouteComponentProps {
  title: string;
  renderContent: any;
  history: any;
  hasMenu: boolean;
  backAction?: any;
}
/**
 * helper Ionic Page which laysout the framework of the page so
 * we dont need to repeat the boilerplate code. We also include
 * the router by default to help with page navigation
 */
const BasicPage: React.FC<BasicPage> = ({
  title,
  renderContent,
  history,
  hasMenu,
  backAction,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar color="primary">
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            {hasMenu ? <IonMenuButton /> : null}
            {backAction ? <IonBackButton defaultHref="/" text="" /> : null}
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>{title}</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>{renderContent(history)}</IonContent>
    </>
  );
};

export default withRouter(BasicPage);
```

The `renderContent` was not rendering my page. I haven't figured out what is the cause of that, but I'm now trying to work around that problem.

Comment: what does `withRouter` do? Is that a React method or something custom you wrote?

Comment: ‘withRouter’ is a Higher Order component that wraps around your function component. It is coming from react-router. See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter